# How to implement a cache for web resources? NSURLRequest cache or disk caching?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, image

I have several UITableViews that asynchronously load the images, video, and text from the internet using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection (Think similar to NYTimes app). That works fine. Currently the content isn't cached. I don't need offline access but just want to cache to speed up performance.

What would be best:

- Using NSURLRequest and cachePolicy?
- Saving the images and videos to disk (what about metadata)? How would I store text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the code here: http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage